# Kmeans Clusters' visualization and labeling

Tags: r, nlp, cluster-analysis, k-means, text-mining

I applied kmeans of a set of SMS messages. My goal is to cluster these messages according to their subject. That is to say I want to have cluster of SMS messages that have similar content.

I applied kmeans and everything went okay. When it comes to clusters visualization, I am having some difficulties to make my clusters graphs and plots easy to read.

Also, I want to display the intersection between clusters.

To give you a glimpse about my data, here it is :

```
library(tm)
library(wordcloud)
library(slam)

xml.url <- "http://dit.ie/media/computing/spam.xml"
indata <- xmlToDataFrame(xml.url)
corpus= Corpus(VectorSource(indata$text))
inspect(corpus)
```

output:

> 1] FreeMsg Hey there darling it's been 3 week's now and no word
>   back! I'd like some fun you up for it still? Tb ok! XxX std chgs to
>   send, £1.50 to rcv
>
> 2] WINNER!! As a valued network customer you have been selected to
>   receivea £900 prize reward! To claim call 09061701461. Claim code
>   KL341. Valid 12 hours only.
>
> [3] Had your mobile 11 months or more? U R entitled to Update to the
>   latest colour mobiles with camera for Free! Call The Mobile Update Co
>   FREE on 08002986030
>
> [4] SIX chances to win CASH! From 100 to 20,000 pounds txt> CSH11 and
>   send to 87575. Cost 150p/day, 6days, 16+ TsandCs apply Reply HL 4 info
>
> [5] URGENT! You have won a 1 week FREE membership in our £100,000
>   Prize Jackpot! Txt the word: CLAIM to No: 81010 T&C www.dbuk.net
>   LCCLTD POBOX 4403LDNW1A7RW18
>
> [6] XXXMobileMovieClub: To use your credit, click the WAP link in the
>   next txt message or click here>> http://wap.
>   xxxmobilemovieclub.com?n=QJKGIGHJJGCBL
>
> [7] England v Macedonia - dont miss the goals/team news. Txt ur
>   national team to 87077 eg ENGLAND to 87077 Try:WALES, SCOTLAND
>   4txt/ú1.20 POBOXox36504W45WQ 16+
>
> [8] Thanks for your subscription to Ringtone UK your mobile will be
>   charged £5/month Please confirm by replying YES or NO. If you reply NO
>   you will not be charged
>   ....

Here is my reproducible script de:

```
library(tm)
library(wordcloud)
library(slam)

xml.url <- "http://dit.ie/media/computing/spam.xml"
indata <- xmlToDataFrame(xml.url)
corpus= Corpus(VectorSource(indata$text))
Cleanset=tm_map(corpus, removeWords, stopwords("english"))
Cleanset=tm_map(Cleanset, stripWhitespace)
Cleanset<-tm_map(Cleanset,removeNumbers)
Cleanset<-tm_map(Cleanset,removePunctuation)

dtm<-DocumentTermMatrix(Cleanset)
inspect(dtm)

freq = colSums(as.matrix(dtm))
length(freq)
freq= sort(colSums(as.matrix(dtm)), decreasing = TRUE)
head(freq, 14)

d= dist(t(dtm), method="euclidian")

kfit <- kmeans(d, 15)
```

Now, once kmeans is run, I will print the 15 clusters.

```
cluster= 1:15
for(i in cluster)
   {
cat("Cluster", i, ":", findFreqTerms(tdm_tfxidf[kfit$cluster==i,], 2), "\n\n") 
    }
```

I got the following results:

> Cluster 1 :
>
> Cluster 2 : free now nokia this per help lost
>
> Cluster 3 :
>
> Cluster 4 : entry free may receive text txt win back freemsg now call
>   claim code prize entitled latest mobile cash cost info pounds reply
>   urgent won you message please yes msg nokia new awarded guaranteed
>   service box get your contact draw ppm landline this award numbers top
>   join chat for must ltd stop content can just name admirer rreveal
>   secret specialcall thinks ufind gift music vouchers weekly custcare
>   help calls opt chance tscs premium every bid records our received tfp
>   accident indicate compensation started debt lie arrived
>
> Cluster 5 :
>
> Cluster 6 : apply entry free may receive text txt win freemsg now send
>   weeks call claim code prize selected camera entitled had latest mobile
>   update cash reply urgent week won you message please will delivery msg
>   nokia new complimentary service get your holiday operator landline
>   award real chat for stop freephone date just name mins offer phone
>   mths double orange help tone boxskch tcs chance shopping pound every
>   mates charity collection records enjoy filthy stories
>   freeringtonereply lost scream sister tickled jun
>
> Cluster 7 : apply free may text txt freemsg like now send still xxx
>   call claim customer prize reward valid entitled mobile cash cost from
>   pounds reply urgent won you message wap please will yes delivery msg
>   nokia new awarded bonus ampm guaranteed service box get waiting your
>   contact draw hrs ppm shows account caller this know age chat for per
>   stop arrange friend see content find collect only can just someone
>   looking make congratulations offer hot unsubscribe club easy phone
>   line number pmsg cashbalance currently maximize xmas messages help
>   dating contacted land welcome opt attempt ring important matches texts
>   voucher every sex immediately need collection records give tcrw guess
>   awaiting time our wiv alert would xxxxxxx gender heard not little
>   driving missed bank promotion wks left accident indicate normal santa
>   compensation maybe naughty lisa ask
>
> Cluster 8 : entry free may text txt win back freemsg now send call
>   claim customer prize selected valid winner entitled mobile cash info
>   pounds reply urgent week won you credit message wap charged please
>   ringtone will yes delivery msg nokia new recent guaranteed service get
>   waiting your contact draw hrs last shows trying holiday pmin todays
>   know want for sexy stop order find can just someone make mins video
>   hot phone line number day tone dating land loan opt dear ipod worth
>   ring chance immediately listen tell need talk records got babe pic
>   voicemail who arsenal our great bout goten night promotion httptms
>   widelivecomindex ringtoneking left accident indicate compensation
>   maybe wmlidadafirsttruec bare bum deleted
>
> Cluster 9 : free may text txt now send call claim prize entitled
>   mobile pounds reply urgent won you message please thanks yes delivery
>   msg new recent guaranteed service waiting your contact account
>   landline this know real chat stop find just someone anytime line
>   number land opt immediately records fancies time our freeringtonereply
>   home freemsgfav tonesreply accident indicate compensation maybe skimpy
>   require trudi
>
> Cluster 10 :
>
> Cluster 11 :
>
> Cluster 12 :
>
> Cluster 13 :
>
> Cluster 14 :
>
> Cluster 15 : free may receive text txt win back freemsg fun like now
>   send still word xxx call claim code customer prize valid winner camera
>   entitled latest mobile the cash days from info pounds reply pobox
>   urgent week won you credit message next use wap dont charged please
>   ringtone thanks will yes delivery msg nokia sms tried end new etc
>   awarded bonus recent guaranteed service box get waiting your contact
>   draw hrs last ppm shows trying pmin account expires identifier points
>   private statement unredeemed landline this match todays know top want
>   age chat for services per sexy stop pls content order find only can
>   just name someone admirer looking make rreveal secret specialcall
>   thinks ufind anytime mins offer video unsubscribe pay phone tones
>   weekly line number day fancy interested currently orange messages gbp
>   available half price help tone dating contacted entered poboxntfp land
>   loan welcome opt dear come claims ring chance tscs one voucher every
>   immediately out email listen best store g...

Some clusters are empty and I honestly dont know exactly why ?

Now, I want plot  the dendogram and clusters plot:

```
clusplot(as.matrix(d), kfit$cluster, color=T, shade=T, labels=15, lines=0)
#plot dendogram, use hang to ensure that labels fall below tree
groups <- hclust(d,method="ward.D")
plot(groups, cex=0.9, hang=-1)
rect.hclust(groups, k=15)
```

Here are the outcomes :

[image: Dendogram]

[image: Clusters]

As, you see the dendogram is not good looking and you can't read it. The same problem for clusters plot.

My question is how can I improve these graphs to display only the cluster label ("Cluster 1", "Cluster 2", ...) for both graphics?

Comment: *"As you see"* is not a good way to capture attention ... I suggest you attach a screenshot so that this question is "completely self-contained". Additionally, unless that `spam.xml` file is static, unchanging, and will be around a while, I suggest you change this from "please look at my entire dataset" to "here is a set sample from that set, help me show them", including `dput(...)` from that sample, and apply the answer given to your full dataset. (To me, it makes sense to include the dendogram for the full dataset, but that's just one opinion.)

Comment: All right @r2evans ! I added changes as you asked. Your help will be very much appreciated. Thank you a lot

Comment: K-means doesn't use a distance matrix as parameter, but a data matrix. If youapply it to a `dist`, you create a problematic bias in the data, and don't get interpretable centers anymore.

Comment: please what you mean by Data Matrix ? how can I build it ?

Answer (score 0):

When `plot`ting a cluster, the function includes an option for `labels`.

Using a much simpler example,

```
require(cluster)
d <- mtcars
kfit <- kmeans(d, 8)
hc <- hclust(dist(d), "ave")

plot(hc, hang = -1, 
     labels = paste0("Cluster ", as.character(kfit$cluster)))
```

would label each leaf by the cluster you got from `kmeans` as you asked.